# Incorrect auto-generated SQL query in Spring Boot (JPA) CrudRepository

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, crud-repository

**My repository interfaces**:

`SongsRepository`:

```java
public interface SongRepository extends CrudRepository<Song, Integer> {
    
}
```

`AlbumsRepository`

```java
public interface AlbumRepository extends CrudRepository<Album, Integer> {
    
}
```

---

**My Model classes**:

`Album.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums", schema = "dbo")
public class Album {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "album_id")
    private Integer albumId;
    
    @Column(name = "album_name")
    private String albumName;
    
    @Column(name = "released_by")
    private String releasedBy;
    
    @Column(name = "total_duration")
    private Integer totalDuration;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Song.class)
    private List<Song> songs;

    public Integer getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public void setAlbumId(Integer albumId) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }

    public String getAlbumName() {
        return albumName;
    }

    public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
        this.albumName = albumName;
    }

    public String getReleasedBy() {
        return releasedBy;
    }

    public void setReleasedBy(String releasedBy) {
        this.releasedBy = releasedBy;
    }

    public Integer getTotalDuration() {
        return totalDuration;
    }

    public void setTotalDuration(Integer totalDuration) {
        this.totalDuration = totalDuration;
    }

    public List<Song> getSongs() {
        return songs;
    }

    public void setSongs(List<Song> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
    }
}
```

`Song.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "dbo")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Integer songId;

    @Column(name = "song_name")
    private String songName;
    
    @Column(name = "album_id")
    private Integer songAlbumId;
    
    @Column(name = "song_duration")
    private String songDuration;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Album.class)
    private Album album;

    public Integer getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }

    public void setSongId(Integer songId) {
        this.songId = songId;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public Integer getSongAlbumId() {
        return songAlbumId;
    }

    public void setSongAlbumId(Integer songAlbumId) {
        this.songAlbumId = songAlbumId;
    }

    public String getSongDuration() {
        return songDuration;
    }

    public void setSongDuration(String songDuration) {
        this.songDuration = songDuration;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
    }
}
```

---

**My Controller**:

`SongsController.java`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songs")
public class SongsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songs;
    
    @Autowired 
    private AlbumRepository albums;
    
    @Autowired
    private Services services;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<SongViewModel> getAllSongs() {
        List<SongViewModel> listOfAllSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        songs.findAll().forEach(song -> listOfAllSongs.add(services.translateToViewModel(song)));
        return listOfAllSongs;
    }
}
```

---

**Services class**:

`Services.java`:

```java
@Service
public class Services {

    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songs;
    
    @Autowired
    private AlbumRepository albums;
    
    public SongViewModel translateToViewModel(Song song) {
        SongViewModel model = new SongViewModel();
        model.setSongId(song.getSongId());
        model.setSongAlbumId(song.getSongAlbumId());
        model.setSongName(song.getSongName());
        model.setSongDuration(song.getSongDuration());
        model.setSongAlbumName(albums.findById(song.getSongAlbumId()).get().getAlbumName());
        return model;
    }
    
    public AlbumViewModel translateToViewModel(Album album) {
        AlbumViewModel model = new AlbumViewModel();
        
        return model;
    }
}
```

---

**My View Models**:

`SongViewModel`:

```java
public class SongViewModel {
    private String songName;
    private String songAlbumName;
    private String songDuration;
    private Integer songId;
    private Integer songAlbumId;
    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }
    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }
    public String getSongAlbumName() {
        return songAlbumName;
    }
    public void setSongAlbumName(String songAlbumName) {
        this.songAlbumName = songAlbumName;
    }
    public String getSongDuration() {
        return songDuration;
    }
    public void setSongDuration(String songDuration) {
        this.songDuration = songDuration;
    }
    public Integer getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }
    public void setSongId(Integer songId) {
        this.songId = songId;
    }
    public Integer getSongAlbumId() {
        return songAlbumId;
    }
    public void setSongAlbumId(Integer songAlbumId) {
        this.songAlbumId = songAlbumId;
    }
}
```

---

**Logged SQL query**:
`select song0_.song_id as song_id1_1_, song0_.album_album_id as album_al5_1_, song0_.album_id as album_id2_1_, song0_.song_duration as song_dur3_1_, song0_.song_name as song_nam4_1_ from dbo.songs song0_`

---

**Error**:
`ERROR: column song0_.album_album_id does not exist`

---

[My Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Fci.png) (PostgreSQL 12.10.1)

---

This is my first time using Spring Boot and JPA. What have I done wrong here?

---

From the error message, I am guessing that it is trying to find a column called `album_album_id` which does not exist in my database and as a result is unable to find it; but why is it searching for that particular column? (My guess is I've messed up the relationship attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. `Song` should look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "dbo")
public class Song {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "song_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "song_name")
  private String name;
    
  @Column(name = "album_id")
  private Integer albumId;
    
  @Column(name = "song_duration")
  private String duration;
    
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Album album;
}
```

and `Album` like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums", schema = "dbo")
public class Album {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "album_id")
  private Integer id;
  
  @Column(name = "album_name")
  private String name;
  
  @Column(name = "released_by")
  private String releasedBy;
  
  @Column(name = "total_duration")
  private Integer totalDuration;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "album")
  private List<Song> songs;
}
```

---

By the way,

1. it's a little strange to have song duration formatted as String and album duration as Integer.
2. if you're willing to go from CrudRepository to JpaRepository, you may want to use [Spring data projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) instead of manually recasting your song to SongViewModels

**[Here's a little example of interface projection for your question](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-71183727)**

Comment: *it's a little strange to have song duration formatted as String and album duration as Integer.* Sorry, had not realised that. Thanks for bringing it to my notice :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Song` entity class should be changed like follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "dbo")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Integer songId;

    @Column(name = "song_name")
    private String songName;
    
    @Column(name = "song_duration")
    private String songDuration;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "album_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Album album;

    public Integer getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }

    public void setSongId(Integer songId) {
        this.songId = songId;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public Integer getSongAlbumId() {
        return songAlbumId;
    }

    public void setSongAlbumId(Integer songAlbumId) {
        this.songAlbumId = songAlbumId;
    }

    public String getSongDuration() {
        return songDuration;
    }

    public void setSongDuration(String songDuration) {
        this.songDuration = songDuration;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
    }
}
```

now you can get `alubm_id` by `song` enntity using `song.getAlbum().getAlbumId()`

Comment: What does `@JoinCoumn` do exactly, and why is it not present in the tutorials?

Comment: `@JoinColumn` annotation to map the foreign key column of  `Album` table .